# Sonarqube - Why does java generated lines of code not get populated?

Tags: java, sonarqube, generated-code

I am learning to use Sonarqube 4.3.2 for my Maven based Java projects.  I have things working pretty well, but cannot get the Generated Lines and Generated Lines of Code metrics to populate.

I would love this metric to track how much code out of the total a vendor actually has to manually code vs. generated code we provide via code generation.  It would also help to see the various issues/statistics in general broken out by generated code vs. manual code.

At first I thought perhaps Sonarqube would automatically pick up that any code in the *target/generated-sources* folder and flag it as generated, but that doesn't appear to be working.

I have also tried to annotate the classes with the `@javax.annotation.Generated` annotation, but this did nothing.

Is there something specifically I need to do to flag code as being generated?

Comment: Any error messages you're receiving? Can you post some code or configuration?

Comment: There are no error messages, simply the Generated Lines and Generated Lines of Code fields are empty.

Comment: Who needs code or configuration when you have magic. Complete guess but I'd say you're missing the sonar.sources property. Probably a couple others too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the generated lines and generated lines of code metrics are only populated by the COBOL plugin right now, even though they are visible/available for other types of projects :(.

Too bad, hopefully this will be implemented for the java ecosystem soon.